# Python ctypes issue with arguments calling DLL function

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

I have made many attempts calling a DLL function using a structure as an argument, none of them successful.  I am using Python 2.7.8. Here is my code:

```
from ctypes import c_int, c_bool, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPCSTR, UINT, sizeof
INPUT_PARM, OUTPUT_PARAM, INPUT_PARM_DEFAULT_ZERO = 1, 2, 4
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, c_bool)
paramflags = ((INPUT_PARM, "Size", 0),
              (INPUT_PARM, "ProgrammerExe", r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ChipProgUSB\6_00_05\UprogNT2.exe"),
              (INPUT_PARM, "CommandLine", "/m"),
              (INPUT_PARM, "DebugMode", True))
Programmer = prototype(("ACI_Launch", windll.ACI), paramflags)
Programmer()
```

This is the documentation of the DLL call I am making:

```
ACI_FUNC ACI_Launch(ACI_Launch_Params * params);
typedef struct tagACI_Launch_Params
{
 UINT   Size;             // (in)  Size of structure, in bytes
 LPCSTR ProgrammerExe;    // (in)  Programmer executable file name
 LPCSTR CommandLine;      // (in)  Optional programmer command-line parameters
 BOOL   DebugMode;        // (in)  Debug mode. Programmer window is not hidden
} ACI_Launch_Params;
```

The error is exception: access violation reading 0x00000000
This looks like it is trying to use the Size as a pointer, when I remove the Size argument, it section looks like this:

```
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, c_bool)
paramflags = ((INPUT_PARM, "ProgrammerExe", ...
```

Then it gives:  Procedure probably called with too many arguments (8 bytes in excess)

The DLL is available from phyton.com as a demo.  If you look on the bottom of a hardware page there is a link that does not require any signup.

**UPDATE**: With eryksun's help I fixed my big mistake.  But I continue to have an issue that I now do not know how to fix:

```
from ctypes import c_int, c_bool, WINFUNCTYPE, windll, Structure,POINTER, c_void_p
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPCSTR, UINT, sizeof, HRESULT
class ACI_Launch_Params(Structure):
    _fields_ =  [("Size" , c_int), 
                 ("ProgrammerExe" , LPCSTR ),
                 ("CommandLine" , LPCSTR ),
                 ("DebugMode" , c_bool ),
                 ]
x=ACI_Launch_Params(64,r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ChipProgUSB\6_00_05\UprogNT2.exe","/m",False)

Launch = windll.ACI.ACI_Launch
Launch.argtypes = [POINTER(ACI_Launch_Params)]
Launch.restype = HRESULT
Exit = windll.ACI.ACI_Exit
Exit.argtypes = []
Exit.restype = HRESULT

print "start result",Launch(x)
time.sleep(4)

# prints Added for Debugging
print sizeof(x),x       #OK
print x.Size            #OK
print x._objects        #OK
print x.__sizeof__()    #Crash
print dir(x)            #Crash
print x.__dict__        #Crash
del x                   #Crash

print "stop result",Exit()
time.sleep(3)
```

This consistently starts the application as expected, and the printed return values are 0.  But on exit of the python code, it crashes python.exe.  It seems to be tied to when the structure 'x' is deleted, if I delete it earlier, then it crashes at that point.  I'm guessing that the DLL is releasing the structure, but if that is the case, how do I get this working reliably?

The event logger reports:
`Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x53b1ecd8
Faulting module name: python27.dll, version: 2.7.8150.1013, time stamp: 0x53b1ecd6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00031fe5
Faulting process id: 0x62d8`

Comment: The function takes only one parameter, `ACI_Launch_Params *params`, which is a pointer to a struct that has the actual parameters. Define the struct as a [`Structure`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) subclass.

Comment: If you want default values for the `_fields_`, just override the `__init__` method of the subclass.